# JBPM custom workitem not pausing the process

Tags: jbpm

I have implemented a workflow with intermediate catch signal event in JBPM 6.2.0. I have a custom workitem handler task to check the signal and based on the signal either to pause the workflow or proceed. But the workflow is getting terminated instead of halting at the custom workitem handler till it gets the signal. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Can you attach some of the essential code in your workItemHandler? By "pausing", do you mean you do not invoke WorkItemManager.completeWorkItem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will attach my code. I explored further, thought of using Executor which shall pause the process. Yes 'pausing' means I would like the custom workitem handler to wait till it receives the signal event. i.e. I do not want to invoke WorkItemManager.completeWorkItem() until the condition is fulfilled.